# Как пересчитать высоту объекта window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый, как при ресайз фанкшн пересчитывать высоту за минусом 150-ти пикселей. т.e есть функция которая проверяет высоту окна и если высота меньше определенного значения передавать в определенный класс высоту объекта window, можно ли как-то передавать высоту и пересчитать ее за минусом 150 пикселей, как то так.

```
function msgHeightSize(){
  if ($(window).height() <= '830'){
    $('.msgs-scroll').css( 
      'height', $(window).height()
    );
  } 
}
$(window).load(function() {
  msgHeightSize()
});
$(window).resize(function(){
  msgHeightSize()
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function msgHeightSize(){
  if ($(window).height() <= '830'){
    $('.msgs-scroll').css( 
      'height', (parseInt($(window).height())-150) + "px"
    );
  } 
}
$(window).load(function(){
  msgHeightSize()
});
$(window).resize(function(){
  msgHeightSize()
});
```

```css
.msgs-scroll{
  border:2px solid red;


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="msgs-scroll" ></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! то что нужно.